# Connect to 2 wifi or 1 wifi and 1 internet at the same time

Tags: network-programming, wifi

I have this drone that connects to laptop via wifi. I need to process the images it clicks in real time using a external Web service. Being connected to drone's wifi I'm unable to process the image immediately. The drone to computer protocol 
is ftp over wifi. I want to connect to Internet in the meantime to process the image. Any ideas ?